# Does fungal growth affect buildings?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 2, does fungal growth affect buildings?

Specifically, does it do anything to unburrowed spine/spore-crawlers and flying terran buildings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unburrowed spine/spore-crawlers and flying terran buildings still count as buildings, their attributes do not change (unlike warcraft 3).

Answer (score 5):

No it does not:

> The Infestor's Fungal Growth affects
>   only enemy units within the area of
>   effect, immobilizing them and dealing
>   36 (+30% to armored) damage.

*Source: [Liquipedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Infestor)*